# Estimate a common formula

Tags: approximation

I know this should be easy, but I just can't find the proper search result. Thanks.

> $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n$, what is the estimation value when $n$ is very large?

Some follow-up,

> If $n = 100$, what is the formula to calculate this?

Comment: Define "estimation". I know that for large, large $\;n\;$ a pretty good estimation is $\;e^{-1}\;$ ...

Comment: I've never heard of an "estimation value" but $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1- 1/n)^n = 1/e$, so $(1- 1/n)^n$ is close to $1/e$ if $n$ is large and positive.  This is a standard calculus exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The estimation value when n is very large is $1/e$, where $e$ is the well known mathematical constant.

\begin{gather}
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{n-1}{n}\right)^{-n}= \\
=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{n}{n-1}\right)^{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n-1}\right)\right]=e
\end{gather}

Therefore, what you are seeking is $e^{-1}$, or $1/e$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What if n = 100, can you give some link or formula on this?

Comment: If n = 100, then the value is approximately 0.36603234127322950493061602657251738618971207663892369140595737269931704475072474818719654351002695040066156910065284327471823569680179941585710535449170757427389035006098270837114978219916760849490001. Source: www.wolframalpha.com